# ActiveRecord boolean validation accepting non-boolean values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to validate that an attribute is a boolean, i.e. true or false.

From the Rails guide I expected

```
validates :new_out_of_stock, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
```

to work, but it accepts non-boolean values (e.g. "Hi") as valid:

```
irb> ip = ItemPrice.new
irb> ip.new_out_of_stock = "Hi"
=> "Hi"
irb> ip.valid?
=> true
irb> ip.errors.messages
=> {}
```

It correctly rejects `nil` and accepts true and false.

All the documentation on the Internet that I've read says that this is the correct way to validate a boolean attribute. Why doesn't it work?

Edit: Here's the class definition:

```
class ItemPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item, counter_cache: true

    validates :new_out_of_stock, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that non-boolean values are coerced to booleans when they're assigned to the attribute, causing them to pass the validation.

See:

```
irb> ip.new_out_of_stock
=> nil
irb> ip.new_out_of_stock = "hi"
=> "hi"
irb> ip.new_out_of_stock 
=> false
```

and clearly `false` is a valid boolean value, so the field passes.

Comment: experiencing the same and am unable to use validations to raise errors for non-boolean input

Answer (score 1):

It's not accept non-boolean values (e.g. "Hi") as valid, you just need to do this:

```
irb> ip.new_out_of_stock="Hi"
=> "Hi"
irb> ip.valid?
=> false # so it's not accept "Hi"
irb> ip.errors.full_messages
=> ["New_out_of_stock is not included in the list"]
irb> ip.errors.messages
=> {:new_out_of_stock=>["is not included in the list"]}
irb> ip.errors.messages[:new_out_of_stock]
=> ["is not included in the list"]
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this in your model:

```
validate :require_boolean

def require_boolean
  errors.add(:new_out_of_stock, "is not included in the list") unless self.new_out_of_stock.in?([true, false])
end
```

Comment: I just did that, and `ip.errors.messages[:new_out_of_stock]` was `nil`. It must be something to do with my particular class, then.

Comment: Errors on other fields (that's why ip.valid? returns `false` for me), but nothing to do with new_out_of_stock.

Comment: I've removed all of the validations for other fields and it still doesn't work. I've updated the question with the class definition I'm using, if that's of any use.

Comment: Bizarre. I'll try it out in a clean project.

Comment: Nope, even in a new project it's the same. Really weird, and I'm on Rails 4.0.2. Are you on version >= 4?

Comment: No. I'm using Rails 3.2.9.

Comment: I think I've found the cause. Hang on, I'll put it in an answer. I have no idea why it'd be different for you, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the syntax slightly to the following

```
validates :new_out_of_stock, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
```

This has worked for me in the past