# Setting a model's boolean value to a string makes it false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Answer` that has a `response` attribute which is a boolean. If I set the `answer.response` to, say, `'abcde'`, the response gets set to `false`.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer_sheet
  belongs_to :question

  validates :response, inclusion: [true, false]
end

class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    answer = Answer.find_or_initialize_by(
      answer_sheet_id: answer_params[:answer_sheet_id],
      question_id: answer_params[:question_id]
    )
    answer.response = answer_params[:response]
    answer.save

    render json: answer, status: :created
  end
end
```

Any idea why this is happening? I'm flummoxed. I would have expected the validation to fail.

Comment: Can you try to add validation as validates :response, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}

Comment: @Icicle that has the same effect. `answer.save` returns `true` and the response is false.

Comment: Coercion; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20657344/438992 for example.

Comment: why wouldn't this be coerced to true?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not finding an already saved record? Are you sure that it's actually getting saved if not? Have you inspected errors?